# How do I connect to an existing CloudSearch domain in boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm just starting to work with boto to connect to Amazon CloudSearch.

I got the examples working, but I can't find any examples of connecting to an existing domain, all the examples create a new domain.

Poking around, I found get_domain, but that fails if I call it on the connection object.

```
>>> conn.get_domain('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Layer2' object has no attribute 'get_domain'
```

Any suggestions as to how I can connect to an existing domain?

[edit]
I started from this: http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/cloudsearch_tut.html

So, all I'm doing this

```
import boto
conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can either do `conn.list_domains()` which will return a list of Domain objects for all of your current domains or you can do `conn.lookup('foo')` which will return a Domain object for the specified domain name.

Comment: Thanks! (I deleted a previous comment about this not working; it was operator error).

Comment: calling conn.lookup('name') raises the following error: AttributeError: 'Layer2' object has no attribute 'lookup'. Searching through the code, I can't find a 'lookup' method within CloudSearch.

Comment: Hmm.  The cloudsearch.layer2 module definitely defines a ``lookup`` method.  It has had it since 2012/08/22 when it was added with this commit (https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/87cc02e496f0f803a07274b8976d14a45663a4ee). Perhaps you are using an older version of boto?

Comment: Bah, just upgraded my boto to 2.9.5 and lookup is not found, I guess it's been moved since ?

Comment: It's still there.  It's in ``boto/cloudsearch/layer2.py``.

Comment: `boto.connect_cloudsearch` returns an instance of layer1. I've used `boto.connect_cloudsearch2` which uses layer2 and has the `lookup` method.

Answer (score 7):

**This is the perfect solution.**
I am using boto 2.38.0

I had same issue which are faced by other. Then i made this script to connect aws search domain and get result

```
import boto.cloudsearch2
from boto.cloudsearch2.layer2 import Layer2
from boto.cloudsearch2.domain import Domain

# from boto.cloudsearch.domain import Domain
conn = boto.cloudsearch2.connect_to_region("xxxxxx",
                aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxx',
                aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxx')

domain_data =  conn.describe_domains('domaainname')

domain_data = (domain_data['DescribeDomainsResponse']
                          ['DescribeDomainsResult']
                          ['DomainStatusList'])

domain = Domain(conn, domain_data[0])
search_service = domain.get_search_service()
results = search_service.search(q="abc")

print map(lambda x: x, results)
```

**Let me know any error. I hope this will work for all.**

Answer (score 2):

Using boto 2.36, I got this working by taking a look at the source code.

```
import boto.cloudsearch
# login to AWS
conn = boto.connect_cloudsearch2(region="us-west-1",
                aws_access_key_id='xxxxx',
                aws_secret_access_key='xxxxx')


# get the right Domain:
domain = conn.lookup('toolbox')

print domain
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me,
we have only one domain,
dom = Domain(con,con.describe_domains()[0])

Answer (score 0):

I initially implemented the connection using the Layer2 approach:

`Layer2(region='region name').lookup('domain name')`.

However, after some profiling I found the latency in creating a connection to be *very* high.

When I say very high, I mean the time to create a connection was rivaling the time to actually perform the query and get a response (> 500ms in most cases).

My solution, therefore, was to create the `Domain` directly. **Note: this solution is brittle, but it does decrease latency significantly**

You can create the domain by doing something like (many of these values can be found by doing `aws cloudsearch describe-domains`):

```
        domain = Domain(boto.cloudsearch2.connect_to_region('region name'), {
            'Created': True,
            'Deleted': False,
            'Processing': False,
            'RequiresIndexDocuments': False,
            'DomainId': 'domain_id',
            'DomainName': 'domain_name',
            'SearchInstanceCount': 2,
            'SearchPartitionCount': 1,
            'DocService': {
                'Endpoint': 'doc_service_endpoint',
            },
            'ARN': 'domain_arn',
            'SearchService': {
                'Endpoint': 'search_service_endpoint'
            }
        })
```