# amazon cloudsearch cannot add document with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudsearch

I am trying to use the latest boto 2.36(?) with cloudsearch, I made connection using connect_cloudsearch2:

```
user =    {
        'id': 4,
        'username': 'daniella',
        'last_activity': 1334253279,
        'follower_count': 7,
        'location': 'USA',
        'snippet': 'Just like Dan, I like to watch a good sunset, but heights scare me.',
    }
doc_service = domain.get_document_service()
for user in users:
   doc_service.add(user['id'], user['last_activity'], user)
   #doc_service.add(user['id'], user) #this does not work either
complete = doc_service.commit()
```

Error I get is on the line with the doc_service.add (it comes straight from the docs):

```
TypeError: add() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

If the commented "doc_service.add" line is used instead of the line above it, the error is:

```
boto.cloudsearch2.document.CommitMismatchError: Incorrect number of adds returned. Commit: 1 Response: 0
```

No documents get added/committed in either case.
The cloud seems very difficult to use... anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

Today i faced same issue with boto. I tried passed some time and finally find solution.

Use cloudsearch2. I am using **boto2.38.0**

```
import boto.cloudsearch2
from boto.cloudsearch2.layer2 import Layer2
from boto.cloudsearch2.domain import Domain

# from boto.cloudsearch.domain import Domain
conn = boto.cloudsearch2.connect_to_region("xxxxxx",
                aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxx',
                aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxx')

domain_data =  conn.describe_domains('domaainname')

domain_data = (domain_data['DescribeDomainsResponse']
                          ['DescribeDomainsResult']
                          ['DomainStatusList'])

domain = Domain(conn, domain_data[0])

doc_service = domain.get_document_service()

user =    {
        'id': 4,
        'username': 'daniella',
        'last_activity': 1334253279,
        'follower_count': 7,
        'location': 'USA',
        'snippet': 'Just like Dan, I like to watch a good sunset, but heights scare me.',
    }


doc_service.add(user['id'],  user)
result = doc_service.commit()
print result
```

**Let me know is this solved your issue?**

For get_search_service, you can find my answer.

[How do I connect to an existing CloudSearch domain in boto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12763129/how-do-i-connect-to-an-existing-cloudsearch-domain-in-boto)

Comment: I initially had the same issue...I have changed the code using cloudsearch2 and it is working fine! Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you vote up this answer, so, it will be helpful for other and can save time.

Comment: dispite of using cloudsearch2 I get 'boto.cloudsearch2.document.CommitMismatchError: Incorrect number of adds returned.' this error